# A question on a number raised to a logarithm

Tags: logarithms

$$3^{\log(x)}-2^{\log(x)}=2^{\log(x+1)}-3^{\log(x-1)}$$ thanks for the correction Michael rozenberg. Now if you could please tell me how to solve this problem, I would appreciate it.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for writing tips.

Comment: Put the exponent in {} so 2^log(x+1)  becomes 2^{log(x+1)}.  (The {} say to treat everything in as a chunk.  If you leave it out only the first letter is formatted.) Put a \ before log to indicate it is a special math function so 2^{\log (x+1)}.  The put everthing between \$ signs:  So \$2^{\log (x+1)}\$ which will be rendered $2^{\log (x+1)}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's $$3^{\log(x)}-2^{\log(x)}=2^{\log(x+1)}-3^{\log(x-1)},$$
for which you can write the following:

3^{\log(x)}-2^{\log(x)}=2^{\log(x+1)}-3^{\log(x-1)}